# Icons in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Does anyone know how to add icons like this in the navigation drawer?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvzOb.png

(cant add images until I have 10 rep. points)

Comment: Oh, wonderful. Thank you, I couldn't find that. @BrainCash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the `DraweLayout`is a `ListView`. So, you must set a custom adapter to the `ListView`, providing on the `getView` method the view desired. A good [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).